# How to require a checkbox be checked in ASP.Net using Formvalidation.io and Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, ajax, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, formvalidation.io

This should be easy, but I've yet to arrive at a solution. I'm using

- ASP.Net Ajax
- Bootstrap 3.3
- Formvalidation.io v0.7.0

I have a single check box that the user has to check before the form can be submitted. The following doesn't work. (I have other validation on the page that does work, so it's not the set up of Formvalidation.io)

Any suggestions appreciated!

```html
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 right padLabel">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <label class="control-label">
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRelease" runat="server" Text="Yes, I agree" data-fv-notempty="true" data-fv-notempty-message="Release is required" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may approach you one solution:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return CheckCheckbox();" Text="Save" />
```

And in a head part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckCheckbox(){
        var checkbox_control = document.getElementById('your_checkbox_id');
        if (checkbox_control.value.length == 0)
        {
            alert('Check the checkbox please');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It takes your checkbox's value and checks for a length. If length is zero, it means that your checkbox have no value. And it return your false, which means that OnClick method of your button will not execute until your checkbox will have a value.